# Should recommendation letters be from the home university of a student?

Tags: graduate-school, recommendation-letter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a recommendation have to be from a professor from your university?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/does-a-recommendation-have-to-be-from-a-professor-from-your-university)

I am applying to an applied math graduate program in the US. I frequently interact with professors from other institutions. Some are from math departments and others are from other departments. Could they write letters of recommendation for me?

Comment: Similar question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/does-a-recommendation-have-to-be-from-a-professor-from-your-university

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they could write letters for you.  In fact, strong letters from faculty outside your home department or university will likely *help* your application.

One caveat, though: A strong recommendation letter must praise your potential for research *in applied mathematics*, not just in the writer's native discipline, in specific and credible detail.  Moreover, it must be clear that the writer has the expertise to judge that potential; that expertise may not be clear from their departmental affiliation alone.  So you should consider asking your references to include a short paragraph in their letter, explaining their own applied math background (either as a researcher themselves or as a reference for past successful grad students).